# How to execute runCommand with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, text, mongoid

I have text index in MongoDB and want to use [text](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/) command for searching in my collection. Can't find this functionality in Mongoid.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongoid/hJRbaNMy6w4/PEolIR2SJ2oJ)?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to find the solution as I am also a mongoid user. I haven't found anything specific related to search text in mongoid other than where query. After little investigation I have found [mongoid_search](https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search) gem which could be useful for search text.

It has one limitation that is written in very first line of readme is "If your searchable model is big (i.e. 1.000.000+ records), solr or sphinx may suit you better." If you have so you need to configure solr or elasticsearch for better performance. If you are going to deploy on heroku then please develop in that consideration too.

May be this would help you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Recently ran into a similar situation.  You can run a search command in Mongoid in the following manner:

```
session = Mongoid.session('default')
session.command({"text" => 'my_collection', 'search' => 'whatever'})
```

Makes for a nice mixin:

```
# mixins/search.rb
module Mixins
  module Search

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods

      def search(query)
        session = Mongoid.session('default')
        session.command({"text" => collection.name, 'search' => query})
      end

    end

  end
end
```

That way you can just `include Mixins::Search` into your models and use `Model.search 'whatever'` to search for stuff.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer. I would tweak the Mixin to use Mongoid's mongo_session document class method.